# Opposite of Key Listener

Tags: keyboard, keylistener

I have worked with Keyboard Listeners before, but for this current program that I'm working on I am trying to do the exact opposite. I want to have a timer running in the background, and every thirty seconds the pc that it is running on thinks that a key has been pressed. I know that there is a way to do it, but I don't know what to research because I don't know what it is called. Can anyone give me some recommendations? or links?

Comment: You should add more information to your question. Like in which programming language you would like to achieve that? Do you use any GUI library?

Comment: I haven’t actually decided what language yet. I usually create GUI’s in JFrame, but I’m just asking conceptually what it would be called so I can conduct my own research.